# Error en APP.js con la creacción de una carpeta de componentes

Tags: reactjs

Soy nuevo en react.

Cree una carpeta para mis archivos de header dentro de src-components-Header-Header.jsx

en APP.JS tengo lo siguiente.

```html
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Header } from './components/Header/Header';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
  Hola <Header/>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Pero me sale un error en la consola

```html
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Header' in 'C:\Users\Javier\Documents\geocartosweb\geocartos\src'
ERROR in ./src/App.js 6:0-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Header' in 'C:\Users\Javier\Documents\geocartosweb\geocartos\src'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

No sé como solucionarlo, si la dirección del componente header está bien.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que has exportado el componente Header 'export default Header;'.
A la hora de importar tu componente debes hacerlo sin las llaves.

```
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
```

Creo que con eso sería suficiente con la información que das. Un saludo.